# Edit method not working properly in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have displayed the data from API. But I can't edit the data properly. When I try to edit a single row it will automatically hide the others row. Here is my code. Please check

**HTML**

```
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Consent Type</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Updated At</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Content</strong></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let consent of SystemConsent">
                        <td *ngIf="!editorStatus">{{consent.fileName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="editorStatus && consent.consentFileId === selectedEditCellId"><input type="text" value="{{consent.fileName}}" class="form-control"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!editorStatus">{{consent.type}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="editorStatus && consent.consentFileId === selectedEditCellId"><input type="text" value="{{consent.type}}" class="form-control"></td>

                        <td>{{consent.updatedAt}}</td>

                        <td *ngIf="!editorStatus">{{consent.status}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="editorStatus && consent.consentFileId === selectedEditCellId"><input type="text" value="{{consent.status}}" class="form-control"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!editorStatus" [innerHTML]="consent.content"></td>
                        <td *ngIf="editorStatus && consent.consentFileId === selectedEditCellId">
                            <ckeditor name="htmlEditor" [config]="config" [editor]="Editor" [(ngModel)]="consent.content" skin="moono-lisa" language="en">
                            </ckeditor>
                        </td>

                        <td><button class="btn trans-btn list-head-btn ng-star-inserted btn-gradient" (click)="changeEditor(consent.consentFileId)">Edit</button></td>
                        <td><button [disabled]="!editorStatus" class="btn trans-btn list-head-btn ng-star-inserted btn-gradient" (click)="getEditorValue(consent.consentFileId)">Save</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

**Typescript**

```
SystemConsent: any = [];
  public selectedEditCellId;

getAdminSystemPrefrences() {
    this.adminDashboardService.getSystemPreferences().then(resp => {
      this.SystemConsent = resp['data'].consent;
    });
}

  changeEditor(cellId) {
    this.selectedEditCellId = cellId;
    this.editorStatus = true;
    console.log(this.selectedEditCellId);
  }
  
  getEditorValue(cellId) {
    this.selectedEditCellId = cellId;
    this.editorStatus = false;
  }
```

Please help me to reach out this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you click 'edit', the `editorStatus` gets set to `true` and the `selectedEditCellId` gets set to the id of the item / row that is currently being edited.

If we look at these lines:

```
<td *ngIf="!editorStatus">{{consent.fileName}}</td>
<td *ngIf="editorStatus && consent.consentFileId === selectedEditCellId"><input type="text" value="{{consent.fileName}}" class="form-control"></td>
```

We notice that for the items that are NOT being edited, neither of these `*ngIfs` evaluate to `true` - because:

1. `editorStatus` is set to true
2. `consent.consentFileId` is not equal to the `selectedEditCellId` for the row item.

This is also the reason why the `{{consent.updatedAt}}` is being displayed for the other rows.

A possible fix to the problem would be to change:

```
<td *ngIf="!editorStatus">{{consent.fileName}}</td>
```

to

```
<td *ngIf="!editorStatus || consent.consentFileId !== selectedEditCellId">{{consent.fileName}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this method

Comment: It's working fine thank you somuch